# How to set opacity of an image respective to the DIV it is in

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="mmItemStyleChild">
    <img src="theImages/home.png" class="mIcon vertAlign mmm1" id="mH1" /> <img src="theImages/emptyImg.png" class="mSpacerStyle" /><span id="mH" class="vertAlign mmm">Home</span>
</div>
<div class="mmItemStyleChild">
    <img src="theImages/MakeAnAppt_icon.png" class="mIcon vertAlign mmm1" id="mMW1" /> <img src="theImages/emptyImg.png" class="mSpacerStyle" /><span id="mMW" class="vertAlign mmm">My WESTMED</span>
</div>
<div class="mmItemStyleChild">
    <img src="theImages/FindaProvider_icon.png" class="mIcon vertAlign mmm1" id="mFP1" /> <img src="theImages/emptyImg.png" class="mSpacerStyle" /><span id="mFP" class="vertAlign mmm">Find a Provider</span>
</div>
```

I would like the image on the left to be animated opacity by 35% when the text on the right is hovered, and then back to normal when the mouse leaves.

So for example, if I hover over `Home`, the home image should be animated.

I have the following JQuery which does something similar:

```
$(".mmm {home}").hover(function(){
    $("{.mmm1 [HOME]}").stop().animate({"opacity": .35}); //on text hover set it at 35% opacity
},function(){
    $("{.mmm1 [HOME]}").stop().animate({"opacity": 1}); //on text hover leave set it to default opacity
});
```

How do I make it so that each text will only work on the image on the same DIV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('.mmm').hover(function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.mIcon').stop().animate({'opacity': .35});
}, function(){
    $(this).closest('div').find('.mIcon').stop().animate({'opacity': 1});
});
```

`.closest()` will traverse the dom for the closest element, which in this case will be the parent (you could also use .parent() here). Then `.find()` will traverse it's children to find the element. The rest is the same as your code. This will make sure that the animations only affect the image associated with the text you hover.

Comment: I have two images in the DIV, will it animate only the first image?

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge replace `find('img')` with `find('.mIcon')` and is done

Comment: DONE! Thank you. The first code wasn't working but the edited one is :) Thanks again

Comment: @Danko Yeah, you're definitely right. Moving too fast not paying attention to selectors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.mmItemStyleChild span').hover(function() {
    var $img = $(this).siblings('.mm1'); // define image object;

    $($img).stop().animate({
        opacity: .35
    });
}, function() {
    var $img = $(this).siblings('.mm1'); // define image object;
    $($img).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
});
```

Comment: I have two images but only the first one I would like to animate.

Comment: Getting a Syntax error for the first and the middle brace :/

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge Sorry about that, just updated my answer.